# Java: Compare each word pair of substring in a sentence to find whether it is key in hashmap

Tags: java

I have a hashmap which has keys. keys can be any combination of words from a given sentence. I am trying to write logic to find whether a every possible substring from a given sentence is present in map as a key or not, but not getting result.

String = "This is my bag which I purchased yesterday".
HashMap Keys:
first key  = "is my"
second key = "which I purchased"

The code I have written is, but i am not getting result:

```
private static String getSubStringToMatch(String[] s){
        String temp = "";
        int counter = frequencyOfConcatenation;
        for(int j = 0; j< s.length;j++){
            for(int i = 0; i<counter;i++){  
                temp = temp +" "+ s[i];
            }
            System.out.println(returnSubString(temp.split(" ")));
            temp = "";
            counter--;
        }
        return temp;    
    }

    private static String returnSubString(String[] string){
        String s = "";
        for(int i= 0; i<string.length;i++){
            s=s+" "+string[i];
        }
        return s.trim().toUpperCase();
    }
```

Comment: Can you clearly state the requirement for the `key`? Does the algorithm needs to handle all the permutation of the sub-strings? The set of sub-strings has to be contiguous or not?

Comment: yes it needs to handle all permutations because we are not sure which combination can be key

Comment: yes it has to be contiguous.

Comment: So the keys for "This is a test" should be ["This", "is", "a", "test", "This is", "is a", "a test", "This is a", "is a test", "This is a test"]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that finding all possible substrings of a sentence is the best way to reach your goal here.

Here's an alternative option: We have a `HashMap<String, Object> map` of sentence substrings to some value.

We can look up this map with a sentence through the following stream call:

```
    List<Object> objectsThatMatchSentence = map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> sentence.contains(entry.getKey()))
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This loops through all entries in the HashMap, and filters out keys that are not contained within the variable `sentence`. It then maps each entry to the associated value, and then returns a list of these values, which is a list of objects that match your requirements.